# Do I need to standardize my likert data for principal component analysis?

Tags: pca, cross-validation, descriptive-statistics, likert

I am doing a PCA and I am analyzing 15 performance variables. All of these variables are measured from a scale of 1-5 (1 very dissatisfied, 5 very satisfied).

Do I need to standardize the data for analysis? Can I just use the original data / mean-corrected data for analysis?

Comment: Yes but many tools (sklearn) will do this for you.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.